# Difference and benefit of using Declarative Base Classes instead of table objects in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy, declarative

I am having problems understanding the benefit of the usage of declarative classes in SQLAlchemy.

As I understand the ORM is a way to apply the concept of database tables to the class system of OOP. However I don't understand why the table class doesn't already satisfy this requirement.

So to form my question via an example:

What is the benefit of using this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
class User(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'users'

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String(16))
     fullname = Column(String(60))
     nickname = Column(String(50))
```

Instead of this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
metadata = MetaData()
user = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(16)),
    Column('fullname ', String(60)),
    Column('nickname ', String(50))
)
```

The latter one is already a class representation, isn't it? Why are we building another class over the already existing table class? What's the benefit?

Comment: "The latter one is already a class representation, isn't it?" — no, a `Table` **object** is a representation of the SQL table, used to form queries etc.

Comment: Ah okay - so user is an object, while User is a class. And any object I create for the class User will be an entry in the object user.

So the beneftit is that rows in the table are represented via objects in the first case.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question recently, you can refer to [SQLAlchemy doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-mapping).

> Some examples in the documentation still use the classical approach, but note that the classical as well as Declarative approaches are fully interchangeable.

I think the benefit of using Declarative Mapping is that,

1. more convinent to use foreign key.
2. when you want to create table with some table_args/mapper_args, just write in all down in the class.